# Redirecting/proxying a HTTP request to a secondary HTTP server

Tags: sockets, networking, restbed

I use a C++ library called [restbed](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed) as a webserver to deliver static HTML files. On the **same** machine I have another webserver running, and I would like to redirect some of the incoming connections to restbed. Depending on the request I would make the decision to redirect certain requests to the other server.

Is it technically possible **and** advised to connect two sockets with each other, if I get access to the underlying socket of the incoming HTTP connection?

If not, what would be a common approach for this? I can only have one TCP port for both services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can respond to an HTTP request by opening a connection to another HTTP server, forwarding the request to that server, and then forwarding the response back to the original client. In fact it's common for Internet-facing systems to include some kind of "front end" or "reverse proxy" or "L7 load balancer" or "API gateway" that does exactly this, often applying some kind of authentication, input validation, or routing logic in the process.

If you're building this yourself, it's not quite as simple as just opening a socket to the second HTTP server and forwarding the request verbatim. You should use some HTTP client library to send the request to the second server. In other words, the HTTP server that receives the original request should then turn around and be an HTTP client for the second server. When preparing the request for the second server, you should copy some but not all of the data out of the original request.

- You should copy the HTTP method and URL.
- You should probably not copy the scheme (http: or https:) because how the client chose to connect to the original server doesn't have to influence how that server will connect to the second server; you might be using HTTPS for the original server but forward requests using HTTP.
- You should not copy the `Host` header unless for some reason the second server has been configured to respond to the same host name as the original server.
- You should not copy headers that will confuse the HTTP client library you're using to connect to the second server. For example, if the client sends you `Accept-Encoding: gzip` then it is claiming to be able to accept gzipped responses, but if you forward that header, the second server will think that the HTTP client library you're using in your server can accept gzipped responses, whether it actually can or not.
- You should forward cache control headers if you want the second server to be able to send `304 Not Modified` if the client already has the file.

If you're just serving static files from the second server, then you can probably get something to work just by sending the HTTP method and URL only and ignoring the other request headers.

It's a similar story on the response side. You should probably copy some headers like `Content-Type`, but others, like `Content-Length`, will be set by your server, so you should not copy those headers. Try starting out by copying no headers and see if it works, then copy individual headers to address issues you discover. You will probably at least need to copy `Content-Type`.

HTTP has a lot of features, and I can't hope to go through all the possible situations here. The point I want to get across is that you can't just copy all the headers from one request or response into the other, because some of them may not apply, but you can't just copy none of them either. You have to understand what the headers do and handle them appropriately.

Which headers you should preserve depends a lot on how much handling of the request and response you're doing in the first server. The more the first server handles or interprets the request and/or response, the more its interaction with the second server becomes independent of its interaction with the client, and the fewer headers you should copy.

Comment: Wow, thank you a lot for the detailed answer! That is exactly what I needed. Especially the L7/reverse proxy were the keywords I needed. Again, thanks a lot!